# Monitor a start of process in windows, then execute something (stop another process/service)

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, service

can someone think of a solution for something like this? :

Program/script logic: It would constantly monitor the windows OS for a process starting within it (***1.exe) (I guess it could constantly run via task scheduler to do the constant monitoring?) , while it sees that ***1.exe is running, it would kill/end another process ***2.exe, and once ***1.exe would go away, it would no longer be stopping the ***2.exe process.

I think it could be either a bash script, powershell script, or a windows service?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Register-CimIndicationEvent` cmdlet to register for events raised by `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` WMI class:

```
# Define which events to listen for
$NewProcessQuery = "SELECT ProcessId,ProcessName FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace WHERE ProcessName LIKE '%1.exe'"

# Define the code to run every time a new process is created
$ProcessAction = {
    # See if any instances of *2.exe processes are running
    if(($TargetProcess = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name LIKE '%2.exe'"))
    {
        # Terminate them
        $TargetProcess |Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Terminate
    }
}

# Register for the event
Register-CimIndicationEvent -Query $NewProcessQuery -SourceIdentifier ProcessCreated
```

Comment: thanks! the process names would be edited, as well as the 'ProcessCreated' part that would similar to the first process, correct? would this be ran one-time with powershell and from then it would just constantly monitor the process listed? also, is this 2012 windows server and up?

Comment: This will work on 2012 and up, yes. Personally I would go for a Scheduled Task with the `-NoExit` argument. The `ProcessCreated` is the source identifier for the event registration, it could be anything.

Comment: hmm, ok, out of this list, would all ways for searching for a process name work?: 'exactname.exe' ; '%almostexact%' ; '%almostexact.exe%.exe' ; '%endoftheprocessname% ?

Comment: 1,2 and 4 would. Please see the [WQL operator reference for more info on LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392263(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: for #3 I accidentally put two .exe parts. so I have tried times multiple times now but can't get it to work. :| the program that's supposed to be ended is an .exe *32 but what I would launch initially is an msi installer, I wonder if maybe it doesn't detect it when I say its an .exe *32? hmm

Comment: also, do you think there is a similar solution for 2008/2008r2 win servers?

Answer (score 0):

So since the solution above was for only windows 2012 and up, I decided to try another solution. This should work for regular processes, but I'll have to try something else rather than %ERRORLEVEL% because the process I'm monitoring is originally an msi installer and seems like it returns and errorlevel of 1 all the time (running or not) while regular processes return 0 or 1 depending on the status. The process I'm ending starts back up automatically, that's the reason there's no start service command included in here, timeout was set to 62 seconds because the service starts back up automatically every 60 seconds, a /NOBREAK can be added if wanted to eliminate the possibility of user input starting it (if this would be ran without a task scheduler,etc.)

```
:loop_check

TIMEOUT /T 62 

TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq process.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "process.exe">NUL

IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
GOTO stop_process2
) ELSE (
GOTO loop_check
)

:stop_process2

ECHO killing task

TASKKILL /F /IM process2.exe

GOTO loop_check
```

Answer (score 0):

Read my previous reply/comment before this one for more clarity. This is the final solution that worked for me. A star(*) is included at the end of the 'BeginningOfApplicationName' because the installer/msi I'm detecting has sometimes different names based on it's version, so it finds/finishes the ending (wildcard). Since the name of the process I'm monitoring can have different names, I couldn't compare it to a static string, so I'm comparing it to INFO: , seems thats what windows (2008 and 2012!) both print out when a process is not found.

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

:loop_check

TIMEOUT /T 62

FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq BeginningOfApplicationName*"') DO IF %%x == INFO: (
GOTO loop_check
) ELSE (
GOTO stop_process
)

:stop_process

TASKKILL /F /IM process.exe

GOTO loop_check
```